# Range-v3: Why is ranges::to_vector needed here?

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

I'm trying to compute a reversed `views::partial_sum`. The code below gives the expected result of a non-reversed partial_'min', but I need to use `ranges::to_vector` in order to un-`views::reverse` the final result (since you can't `views::reverse` a `views::partial_sum`). However, when the second `to_vector` is uncommented, the `views::values` of `intermediate2` are all zeros (although the keys are computed correctly). Uncommenting the first `to_vector` will fix this, but I'd like to know why? And whether I it is possible to avoid the first `to_vector`? Or whether should I just not bother with understanding and just chuck in `to_vector`s until the code works.

```cpp
    auto input = std::vector<float>{} | actions::push_back(views::iota(0u, COUNT)) | actions::shuffle(std::default_random_engine{});;

    auto intermediate1 = views::zip(views::iota(0u, COUNT), input)
        //| to_vector
        ;
    auto intermediate2 = intermediate1
        | views::reverse
        | views::partial_sum(
            [](std::pair<unsigned, float> a, std::pair<unsigned, float> b)
            {
                if (a.second > b.second)
                    return b;
                else
                    return a;
            })
        //| to_vector
        ;
    auto ans = intermediate2
        //| views::reverse
        ;

    std::cout << "values  = " << (ans | ranges::views::values | views::take(23)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "indices = " << (ans | ranges::views::keys | views::take(23)) << std::endl;
```

---

**EDIT**
I overlooked that the uncommenting the final `reverse` breaks the code again, even with both `to_vector`s so it must a problem with `reverse` as per Barry's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a range-v3 bug that is a result of `views::reverse` not properly propagating the `value_type`, and so you end up with a `vector<common_pair<unsigned int, float&>>` (note the reference) where you should really be ending up with a `vector<pair<unsigned int, float>>`. This will be fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/1670).

In the meantime, you can fix this yourself by providing an explicit type for the `vector` that you're converting into, via `ranges::to<std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int, float>>>()`.